# Python: Calculate time between current time and last login. (Automated Communication)

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm trying to make a celery task that would send a basic reminder to our users. So in our automated communication project, we have these tasks:

[image]

As you can see there are few actions that are different. So for now I have created a logic that fetches all the users from the DB and then continues by checking the time difference. But for now, I only have set-up for 2 hours or more. How should I use it correctly? I do not want to re-write each if statement because it's bad practice. How should I make it clear and reduce the system load?

```
@app.task
def check_registered_users():
    from apps.users.models import User
    from apps.notifications.models import AutomatedCommunicationNotifications

    day_start = datetime.utcnow().date()
    day_end = day_start + timedelta(days=1)

    users = User.objects.filter(is_active=True, date_joined__range=(day_start, day_end))
    users_that_received_notification = AutomatedCommunicationNotifications.objects.all().values('user__id')
    excluded_users = users.exclude(id__in=users_that_received_notification)

    for user in excluded_users:
        if user.last_login < user.last_login + timedelta(hours=2):
            # Sign-up uncompleted Push notification 2 hours after last login
            template = SiteConfiguration.get_solo().automated_comms_signup_uncompleted

            send_plain_email_task(
                email=user.email,
                subject=template.subject,
                html_message=template.content,
                from_email=f'{settings.EMAIL_FROM_PREFIX} <{settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL}>',
            )
```

P.S `AutomatedCommunicationNotifications` table is for us to track which user has already received a notification.

```
class AutomatedCommunicationNotifications(BaseModel):
    """ Model for automated comms notifications """
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        choices=NotificationTypes.get_choices(),
        default=NotificationTypes.EMAIL_NOTIFICATION
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.phone)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question(s) asked here or really even what you're trying to accomplish. Also would't this statement always be true? `if user.last_login < user.last_login + timedelta(hours=2):` It's like saying `if 1 < 1 + 2:`

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to iterate over your queried users at least once but here are tips that may help:

**models.py**

```py
class User(...):

    # add a field to determine if the user has registered or not
    # set this to `True` when a User successfully registers:
    is_registered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class AutomatedCommunicationNotifications(BaseModel):

    # add a related name field for easier coding:
    user = models.ForeignKey(..., related_name = 'notifications')
```

**tasks.py**

```py
# load packages outside of your function so this only runs once on startup:
from django.models import F
from apps.users.models import User
from apps.notifications.models import AutomatedCommunicationNotifications

@app.task
def check_registered_users():

    # timestamps:
    two_hours_ago = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=2)

    # query for unregistered users who have not received a notification:
    users = User.objects.filter(
        is_registered = False,
        last_login__lt = two_hours_ago # last logged in 2 or more hours ago
    ).exclude(
        notifications__type = "the type"
    ).prefetch_related(
        'notifications' # prejoins tables to improve performance
    )

    for user in users:

        # send email
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with a cron job. You can let it run whenever you want, depends on how fast after your give time frame you want to sent this.

You start with making a folder in your app:
/django/yourapp/management/commands

There you make a python file which contains your logic. Make sure to import the right modules from your views.

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from yourapp.models import every, module, you, need
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
from django.core.mail import send_mail, EmailMessage

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'YOUR HELP TEXT FOR INTERNAL USE'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        # Your logic
```

I added the crontab to the www-data users crontab like this:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
45 3 * * * /websites/vaccinatieplanner/venv/bin/python /websites/vaccinatieplanner/manage.py reminder
```

You can use that crontab file to tweak your optimal time between checks. If you remove the 3 and replace it by a * then you will have it check every 45 mins.